# cd directory doesn't exist?

Tags: python, node.js

So, I made a command called `jel`, which is executable as `jel`. It is run in Python, and when I run `jel doctor`, in `jel.py` it gives me a error(the main file). The code looks like this: *Note that all necessary modules are already imported.*

```
elif arg == 'doctor':
subprocess.call(['cd', 'js'])
ver = subprocess.call(['node', 'version.js'])
subprocess.call(['cd', '..'])
if not ver == version:
    print 'jel doctor: \033[91found that version\033[0m ' + str(version) + ' \033[91mis not the current version\033[0m'
    print 'jel doctor: \033[92mrun jel update\033[0m'
    sys.exit()
```

The `js` file `version.js` is run on node, and looks like this: *All necessary packages are installed*

```
var latest = require('latest');

latest('jel', function(err, v) {
  console.log(v);
  // => "0.0.3" 
  if (err) {
      console.log('An error occurred.');
  }
});
```

It is giving me this error when the `jel.py` file uses `subprocess` to call `cs js` and `node version.js`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/jel", line 90, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['cd', 'js'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
bjskistad:~/workspace (master) $ jel doctor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/jel", line 90, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['cd', 'js'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I believe it is saying the directory doesn't exist, although it does. Do I need to call something else before?

Comment: No, it is saying that the `cd` file doesn't exist. `cd` is a shell built-in, not an executable file.

Comment: @Robᵩ Yes, but the `js` directory is findable and the `version.js` should be run by node then.

Comment: @Robᵩ Plus, I ran it in my bash and it worked.

Comment: But `node`'s current directory won't be `js` when it is run by your Python script.

Comment: I think you're code has yet another problem. What do you expect `ver` to contain?

Comment: @Robᵩ The version node returns. It runs a npm api.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three problems with your code snippet:

- `cd` is a shell built-in, not an executable program. If you want to invoke `cd`, you'll need to invoke the shell.
- The `cd` command only affects the shell in which it runs. It will have no effect upon the `python` program, or any subsequent subprocesses.
- The return code from `subprocess.call()` is not the text that the program wrote to stdout. To get that text, try `subprocess.check_output()`.

Try this:

```
#UNTESTED
elif arg == 'doctor':
ver = subprocess.check_output(['cd js && node version.js'], shell=True)
if not ver == version:
```

Comment: `ver` isn't being set, the check_output is simply printing the version.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out  changing the directory is only reflected  in the subprocess. You should use [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) to change your working directory but another alternative is to specify the *cwd* to subprocess which avoids any need to  *cd* or *os.chdir*:

```
 version = subprocess.check_output(['node', 'version.js'], cwd="js")
```

You should also use `!=` in your if and you probably want to *rstrip* the newline:

```
 if  version != ver.rstrip():
```

Comment: Yes, `cwd="js"` is much preferable to my `cd js &&`.